# Android Java compiler error (compiling old files?!)

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, intellij-idea

I refactored some packages in my IDE and everything seems to be ok. But when I compile my app I get an error that file x.java can't be read in x.java.
Both files are located in the old packages which do not exist anymore.
The package definition is fine in all classes. Also the Manifest is fine.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains.

```
java: error reading K:\APP\src\com\renemaas\android\APP\About.java; K:\APP\src\com\renemaas\android\APP\About.java (The system can't find this path)
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Note: Yeah I have search for nearly 1 hour to solve this problem on my own. I'm new to Android development.

Comment: Have you tried re-building the project?

Comment: This works great!
Thanks a lot.
To rebuild the project go to Build|Rebuild Project

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?